# CakePHP pagination (last param cut)

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have a "little" problem with the Pagination system of CakePHP (1.2). Here is the query:

```
$this->paginate = array (
    'fields'     => array (
       'Content.slug',
       'Content.title',
       'Content.resume',
       'Content.format',
       'Content.image',
       'Content.video',
       'Criteria.name'
    ),
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order'      => 'Content.created DESC',
    'limit'      => 10,
    'contain'    => array (
        'Category',
        'Criteria',
    )
);

$this->set("PRODUCTS", $this->Paginate("Content"));
```

And the code of view:

```
<?php $total_pages  = (int)$paginator->counter(array('format' => '%pages%')); ?>
<?php if($total_pages > 1){ ?>
<div class="paginar">
    <div class="next_pre_arrow">
        <?=$paginator->prev("Anterior", array("class" => "pre", "escape" => false))?>
        <?=$paginator->next("Siguiente", array("class" => "next", "escape" => false))?>
        <div class="pages">
            <span>Página</span> <?=$paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ' | '))?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

What is the problem? The pagination works OK but with a little problem. In the "next" and "prev" buttons, and in the page numbers, the URL is truncated, deleting the last param, for example:

```
"http://www.domain.com/controller-name/caction-name/option-1/option-2"
```

Show paging links with this URL:

```
"http://www.domain.com/controller-name/caction-name/option-1/page:2"
```

NOT the correct:

```
"http://www.domain.com/controller-name/caction-name/option-1/option-2/page:2"
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `$this->paginate('Content')` instead of `$this->Paginate('Content')`? PHP is not case-sensitive, but CakePHP is.

Comment: No, i change it to $this->paginate('Content') but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can customize the links that are generated by the [Paginator helper](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper) using the [`options()`](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperoptions) method.

Specifically, you can use `$options['url']` to pass a custom URL, as if you were setting parameters of a [`link()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link) call:

```
$paginator->options(array(
  'url' => array(
    'controller' => 'YourController',
    'action' => 'your_action'
    'param1' => 'value_1',
    'param2' => 'value_2',
)));
```

Comment: This Work: <?php $paginator->options(array('url' => $LEVEL2)); ?>
$LEVEL2 is the second param, but i dont understand why is need to set the second param.